# Why won't my JavaScript work in a ASP.net web form?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I have no problems running the code as an HTML page. Now, in a web form, the converter simply does nothing. Was trying to migrate it over to a web form page from HTML to use a master page and theme.

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
 <script lang="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    //Convert Logic
    function CelsiusConvert() {
        document.converter.fahrenheit.value = (document.converter.celsius.value * 9 / 5) + 32
        document.converter.kelvin.value = document.converter.celsius.value * 1 + 273.15
    }
    function FahrenheitConvert() {
        document.converter.celsius.value = (document.converter.fahrenheit.value - 32) * 5 / 9
        document.converter.kelvin.value = ((document.converter.fahrenheit.value - 32) * 5 / 9) + 273.15
    }
    function KelvinConvert() {
        document.converter.celsius.value = document.converter.kelvin.value - 273.15
        document.converter.fahrenheit.value =   ((document.converter.kelvin.value - 273.15) * 9 / 5) + 32
    }
 </script>
</asp:Content>

 <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
   <form name="converter">
       <!--Input Fields-->
       Celsius:
        <input type="text" name="celsius" onchange="CelsiusConvert()"/><br />
       Fahrenheit:
        <input type="text" name="fahrenheit" onchange="FahrenheitConvert()"/><br />
       Kelvin:
        <input type="text" name="kelvin" onchange="KelvinConvert()"/><br />
       <!--Convert Button-->
        <input type="button" value="Convert!" />
   </form>
   </asp:Content>
```

Comment: Please read "[How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)" and then improve your question.

Comment: try removing `form` tag and check

Comment: what exactly is the problem you're having?

Comment: Why are people still using webforms? Is this a legacy system you are maintaining?

Comment: you should try and put the script at the bottom of the MasterPage. Because first the MasterPage will load, and then the Content pages will load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Webforms reserves the `<form>` tag so that it can manage the postbacks and take the information back in.

For a start you shouldn't be using the `<form>` tag, you can just put them loose in the page.

To get at them you should give them `id`'s and use [`document.getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) to access them (or use jQuery).

As an aside I don't think that method of accessing the forms is the cross browser compatible either but that doesn't matter with WebForms as you are removing it anyway.

So something like this:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
 <script lang="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    //Convert Logic
    function CelsiusConvert() {
        document.getElementById("fahrenheit").value = (document.getElementById("celsius").value * 9 / 5) + 32
        document.getElementById("kelvin").value = document.getElementById("celsius").value * 1 + 273.15
    }
    function FahrenheitConvert() {
        document.getElementById("celsius").value = (document.getElementById("fahrenheit").value - 32) * 5 / 9
        document.getElementById("kelvin").value = ((document.getElementById("fahrenheit").value - 32) * 5 / 9) + 273.15
    }
    function KelvinConvert() {
        document.getElementById("celsius").value = document.getElementById("kelvin").value - 273.15
        document.getElementById("fahrenheit").value =   ((document.getElementById("kelvin").value - 273.15) * 9 / 5) + 32
    }
 </script>
</asp:Content>

 <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
   <div>
       <!--Input Fields-->
       Celsius:
        <input type="text" name="celsius" id="celsius" onchange="CelsiusConvert()"/><br />
       Fahrenheit:
        <input type="text" name="fahrenheit" id="fahrenheit" onchange="FahrenheitConvert()"/><br />
       Kelvin:
        <input type="text" name="kelvin" id="kelvin" onchange="KelvinConvert()"/><br />
       <!--Convert Button-->
        <input type="button" value="Convert!" />
   </div>
   </asp:Content>
```

I'm not saying this is great JavaScript code but if you just want to get this working so you can continue learning from it that should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

add

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js">
```

it will work

Answer (score -1):

Remove the type and lang attributes and use only:

```
<script>
// Code
</script>
```

Alternative, create an external JS script and implement it with for example this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/custom.js"></script>
```

Comment: it will work with `type` and `lang` atttibute also, the main issue in OP's code is the form tag, that is why the javascript code is not working